# Matlab Calling 'Import Data' with GUI Button

Tags: matlab, import, matlab-guide

I'm working in a GUI in Matlab R2014b that uses some data from a txt file, so i want to call the 'Import Data' window to permit the user select the data from a file when pushing a button. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The function [`uiimport`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiimport.html) is used for importing data interactively. This [seems to be](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/recommended-methods-for-importing-data.html) what gets called by Matlab's toolbar's "import data" button.

Excerpting from the documenatation,

> `uiimport` opens a dialog to interactively load data from a file or the clipboard. MATLAB® displays a preview of the data in the file.
>
> `uiimport('-file')` presents the file selection dialog first.
>
> `S = uiimport(___)` stores the resulting variables as fields in the struct `S`.

So, just set

```
uiimport('-file');
```

as the button's callback.

Comment: Awesome, this is just want i needed